# After reboot, on resumption of uncompression, inflate() is reporting Z_DATA_ERROR

Tags: zip, gzip, zlib, inflate, lossless-compression

Thanks Mark, on resumption, now I get Z_DATA_ERROR

```
case STORED:
   strm->msg = (char *)"invalid stored block lengths";  // got here - Anton
   state->mode = BAD;
```

Just to see I understood your suggestions yesterday:

after inflateInit2()

```
// go to byte offset
ZSEEK64( , , streamCurrentPos, ZLIB_FILEFUNC_SEEK_SET)

if ( streamBits > 0 ) 
{
   // get that byte
   unz64local_getByte( , , &aByte)
   
   // and shift down by the number of bits. This API doing it? 
   inflatePrime ( , streamBits, 8 - streamBits)
   
} else { no bits to insert }

inflateSetDictionary ()
```

And state of uncompression is saved like this:

```
typedef struct state_of_uncompression
{

  ZPOS64_T streamCurrentPos;      // from : unzGetCurrentFileZStreamPos64()
  int      streamBits;            // from : stream.data_type & (~0x1C0), after clearing bits 8,7, and 6
  Byte     dictionary_buf[32768]; // from : inflateGetDictionary()
  uInt     dictLength;            // from : inflateGetDictionary();
  uint64_t output_wrt_offset      // got this already. 

} uncompression_state_info;
```

Comment: Please don't put pseudo-code in your questions, e.g. with missing parameters. Copy and paste the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

What? No.

`inflatePrime ( , streamBits, 8 - streamBits)` makes no sense. And you did nothing with the `aByte` you got.

It should be `inflatePrime(strm, streamBits, aByte >> (8 - streamBits))`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, with the correction to inflatePrime() call, I noticed my 'state->last' is getting set in the first call to inflate() on resumption. 

            NEEDBITS(3);
            state->last = BITS(1); // last is set 
And got here also:
strm->msg = (char *)"invalid code lengths set"; 
And the aByte was: 
unz64local_getByte() OK, aByte = 0x000000D7

All this looks like, my seek is not correct, for inflate() to restart from the correct offset. I will check after seek, if my current pos/offset in the compressed data is same as before reboot, i.e saved-streamCurrentPos.  Thanks.